# Getting error: "Missing keyword" when using case in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, case

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM corp_action_restriction car1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN investment_account inv
    ON CASE
       WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(car1.restriction_value,
                                      '[^|]+',
                                      1,
                                      1),
                        '^[[:digit:]]*$') THEN
        TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(car1.restriction_value, '[^|]+', 1, 1)) =
        inv.investment_account_id
       ELSE
        car1.restriction_value = TO_CHAR(inv.investment_account_id)
       END
```

I'm getting missing keyword error.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this query?

> ORA-00905: missing keyword
> 00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
> *Cause:
> *Action:
> Error at Line: 4 Column: 61

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `return_expr` or `else_expr` cannot be of a boolean expression type.
Moreover the third and fourth arguments(`1`&`1`) of `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` are redundant.

Indeed you don't need a `CASE..WHEN` expression, and if the DB version is `12cR2+`, then consider using

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM corp_action_restriction car1
  LEFT JOIN investment_account inv
    ON TO_NUMBER(
                 REGEXP_SUBSTR(
                               car1.restriction_value, 
                               '[^|]+'
                              )  
                 DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR
                ) = inv.investment_account_id
```

this way, you won't get an error due to conversion

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=487836c52d5284afe9410338aec1c689)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks this is working in 19 version but i am looking for a solution that's work in both 12 and 19 versions of oracle. It seems that we cannot use = in the and condition with case

Comment: I am getting ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis if i use the same sql in oracle 12c

Comment: Then, your DB version should be 12c Release 1, ain't it ? @Vikas

Answer (score 0):

That would be

```
SELECT *
  FROM CORP_ACTION_RESTRICTION CAR1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN INVESTMENT_ACCOUNT INV
          ON INV.INVESTMENT_ACCOUNT_ID =
             CASE
                WHEN REGEXP_LIKE (REGEXP_SUBSTR (CAR1.RESTRICTION_VALUE,
                                                 '[^|]+',
                                                 1,
                                                 1),
                                  '^[[:digit:]]*$')
                THEN
                   TO_NUMBER (REGEXP_SUBSTR (CAR1.RESTRICTION_VALUE,
                                             '[^|]+',
                                             1,
                                             1))
                ELSE
                   CAR1.RESTRICTION_VALUE
             END;
```

In other words, put `inv.investment_account_id` into `ON` clause and then compare it (with a `=`) to case expression's result.